# retrieve value from query string

Tags: asp.net, openid

I am integrating openid in my website.
I am able to retrieve data(ex email) from op provider(by query string).
But different op provider gives data in different key like gmail gives it under openid.ext1.value.alia2 key and yahoo gives it in under some different key.
how should i retrieve value from query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check namespaces. For example, the server may return `openid.ns.ax = http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0`, and that would mean "everything that starts with `openid.ax` relates to the AX extension".
But it could be `openid.ns.qwerty = http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0` as well, and then everything that starts with `openid.qwerty` would be related to the extension.

Your code must read those namespaces and use aliases as defined by those. Read [specifications](http://openid.net/developers/specs) for more information.