# retrieve email id information from openid response

Tags: asp.net, openid

I am storing response from openid provider using

```
NameValueCollection query = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
```

I am sending request for `emailid` as

```
"&openid.ax.type.email=" + 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://schema.openid.net/contact/email"))
```

but receiving emailid in `openid.ext1.value.email` in some case and `openid.ax.value.email` in others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264677/retrieve-value-from-query-string), which I answered.

You *must* check everything starting with "openid.ns." and search for the correct namespace.
You can't depend on it being ax, ext1, or anything else.

Additionally, you can't depend on the name being "email", you still have to check what it's named by checking namespaces in openid.ax.type. (where ax can be any alias, see above)